# Ubuntu 14.04 and google Chrome with touchscreen, no left click

Tags: google-chrome, multi-touch, touchscreen

I am using the Latest version of chrome with 64bit 14.04 running on my Sony Vaio Tab Duo 11. I am trying to use the touchscreen and everything looks great, scrolling is very nice, i can swipe to go back a page, hard press to right click, all the touch events are working. the only thing which isnt working, and it is rather important is left click. If I ta on a link or anything, it simply moves the mouse to hover over it and not click it, i can not select a place to enter text either, because my finger is unable to click.

```
xinput list
```

gives

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Crucialtek co.,LTD Optical Track Pad      id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ N-trig DuoSense Pen                       id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ N-trig DuoSense                           id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sony Vaio Keys                            id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ USB2.0 Camera Front                       id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ USB2.0 Camera Rear                        id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

i have tried

```
google-chrome --touch-devices=(10,14,13,4, i have tried them all)
```

I have also gone into

chrome:///flags
and enabled the touch events and the various touch things, disabled them, tried different combinations, and yet still nothing

thank you

Comment: I am experiencing an almost identical situation, and tried the same steps as mentioned above but with no success. Did you happen to come up with a solution to this? Or would anyone have suggestions? Many thanks!